# Use tapply(dataframe , index, function) in R giving as argument to the function 2 columns

Tags: r, tapply

I would like to use the tapply() function on a dataframe, grouping the rows with the indexing. My problem is that the argument I would pass to the function is not a single column, but a pair of columns. This beacause the 2 columns of the data frame represent x-y points, which are intended as couples. Running tapply(dataframe , indexes , function) gives me the error that indexes has length different from tapply. How can I solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are more than one column to be summarised, use `aggregate` instead of `tapply` (as `tapply` works for a single column)

```
aggregate(.~ indexes, transform(df1, indexes = indexes), FUN = yourfun)
```

---

Or another option is `by`

```
by(df1, list(indexes), FUN = yourfun)
```

---

Or it may be more flexible with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(indexes) %>%
    summarise(across(c(x, y), yourfun), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
indexes = rep(1:2, c(3, 2))
by(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], indexes, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun!! This solved it.